# Preg_replace rules to target more eficiently

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have some shortcodes that are dynamically generated in a post.

[shortcode 1][shortcode 2][shortcode 3] ... [shortcode 77]

I'm using the WP filter function to *content_save_pre* to run a preg_match on the content and remove all numbers from the shortcodes.

So:

[shortcode 1] becomes [shortcode]

...

[shortcode 77] becomes [shortcode]

This is what I use now

```
add_filter( 'content_save_pre' , 'preg_replace' , 10, 1);
funtion preg_replace ($content){
 $content = preg_replace('/shortcode .]/', 'shortcode]', $content);
 return $content;
}
```

My problem is that on some ocasions the double digit shortcodes do not get changed. This way seams to work  (having 2 dots) but there surely is a better way to target the digits so that all of them get removed, regardless of home may there are.

```
$content = preg_replace('/shortcode ..]/', 'shortcode]', $content);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$content = preg_replace('/shortcode \d+\]/', 'shortcode]', $content);
```